# What will happen to my SSN if I leave the US and then move back on a different visa?

Tags: usa

Suppose I study in the US for a few years, and, during the course of my studies, obtain an SSN. Later, I go elsewhere for a few years, but then I decide to come back to the US to, say, take up a job.

Do I get a new SSN, or do I keep my SSN for lifetime like US citizens?

Comment: @TomasBy I don't think so: the SSN is granted by the federal Social Security Administration, and the states have no role in issuing SSNs. If someone has more than 1 SSN it should be an administrative oversight rather than something normal.

Comment: Most students on F1 or J1 visas are eligible for social security numbers. If you get one, it’s for life.

Comment: "you don't think so": what don't you think?  I missed the earlier comment.

Comment: @phoog The comment says that it might depend on which state you return to, which is obviously untrue because the SSA is a federal agency.

Comment: @TomasBy the first block of digits indicated the location of the issuing office, not necessarily the location of the person's residence.  The numbers were always assigned for life.

Comment: New social security numbers are sometimes assigned in case of identity theft. They may be assigned inadvertently if, for example, a young adult applied for one, unaware that a parent obtained one for him/her before he/she was old enough to understand such things.

Comment: @TomasBy the exceptions are shown in the links you've provided in your comments.  It was never meant to happen, but it sometimes does because of administrative error or identity theft.  To stay on point, returning to the US will not result in a new SSN unless something similar has gone wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Social Security Number (SSN), once issued, stays with you for life, regardless of later changes in your status, and regardless of whether you are in the US or not.

Comment: @TomasBy under very limited circumstances that do not include residing outside of the US or returning later in a different immigration status.

Comment: @TomasBy what is your point?  The numbers are assigned for life, and there are some circumstances where exceptions are made.  If someone asks whether a US passport is valid for ten years, is it necessary to add "unless it is cancelled" after saying "yes"?